# CakePHP Pull data from two tables

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two tables in my app: 'Clients' and 'Appointments'

In the appointments table I have a foreign key called 'clientid' which links the tables together. How would I show the appointments for that user?

So for example when viewing a client `/admin/clients/view/201/` I would see the Client details for client 201 and also the appointments for that client.

So far my controller looks like this:

```
class ClientsController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Clients';

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow(array('*'));  
    }

    function admin_view($id = null)
        {
            $this->Client->id = $id;
            $this->set('client', $this->Client->read());
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Edit: Client model

```
class Client extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Client';

    var $useTable = 'clients';
}
```

Edit2: View

```
    <h1><?php echo $client['Client']['lastname']; ?> <?php echo $client['Client']['firstname']; ?> (<?php echo $this->Html->link('Edit', array('action' => 'edit', $client['Client']['id'])); ?>)</h1>

    <p><strong>Date of Birth:</strong> <?php echo $client['Client']['dateofbirth']; ?></p>

    <h3>Appointments</h3>

<table>
    <?php foreach ($appointments as $appointment): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link($appointment['Appointment']['date'],
                array('admin' => true, 'controller' => 'appointment', 'action' => 'view', $appointment['Appointment']['id'])); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup `hasMany` association between `Client`->`Appointment` models (see [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1043/hasMany), exactly as `User`->`Comment` association is), and reverse `belongsTo` association between `Appointment`->`Client` (see same doc).

If your DB tables and keys are named according to [Cake conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions) and you're using PHP 5, this is all that you need:

```
class Client extends AppModel
{
    var $hasMany = 'Appointment';
}

class Appointment extends AppModel
{
    var $belongsTo = 'Client';
}
```

Recursion is set to 1 (as you need it) by default, so if you haven't changed it anywhere - your code should work.

Comment: Which model does that go into?

Comment: `Client` goes into `Client` model, `Appointment` goes into `Appointment` model.

Comment: Okay so how would I show the appointments for the client I'm viewing then? what would I put in the controller for the `admin_view` method? Thanks

Comment: Your current code will work fine. You just need to change your models (so that querying `Client` model as you do now would hook up `Appointment` model also).

Comment: I'll post my current view above. How would I pull the appointments for that client so e.g. `/clients/view/201`

Comment: Do what I suggested with models and then use `debug($client, true, false)` (in your view) and you'll see `Appointment` data yourself - then modify your view accordingly.

Comment: I have done the model stuff. But I gather I need to create a foreach to create a list of appointments but what about linking them with the client i am viewing is cake doing that automatically? Also what do variable do I use? still client or do I use the Appointment one? Cheers

Comment: Same `$client` variable. `Appointment` data is grouped for each `Client` record. **I repeat: try `debug($client, true, false)` in your view and you'll see**.

Comment: Yes I have the debug and can see all the data but what if I have two fields named the same in the different models how do I show the different one if the variable is the same? Also how does it know which to loop like what would I put as my foreach? Cheers

Comment: Your foreach for appointments should be `foreach ($client['Appointment'] as $appointment):`, and you use data inside foreach like this: `$appointment['date']`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your models both models have the association vars set. i.e. in Client model there is a hasMany association set with foreign key client_id and in Appointment model there is belongsTo with foreign key client_id. If this is alright check if in your controllers you are calling find with recursive set to greater than -1.

```
    $this->Client->find('all', 'recursive' => 1);
```

Now in your clients model you should have a $hasMany field like following

```
    var $hasMany = array(
    'Appointment' => array(
        'className' => 'Appointment',
        'foreignKey' => 'client_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => ''
    )
```

And in controller's action where you need to pull all related data, for example in your admin_view action use

```
    $this->set('client', $this->Client->find('first', 'recursive' => 1));
```

Comment: Hi. That just went over my head. Could you show an example of how this would look in terms of code. I'll post my Model above.

Answer (score 0):

you should name the foreign key 'client_id' instead. That way when you bake it, Cake can automatically make the connection.
Also, for your current purpose, recursive=1 would be fine. But I'd suggest to look into Containable. It is a very useful tool.